# Which distribution can be abbreviated  as "LD"?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, definition

Which distribution can be abbreviated as LD and which PDF is expressed as a formula with sum of `erfc()` functions?

$$p(o)=\frac{1}{4\ell} e^{\frac{\sigma^2}{2\ell^2}} \left[e^{\frac{o'}{\ell}}\operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{\ell o'+\sigma^2}{\sqrt{2}\ell\sigma}\right) + e^{-\frac{o'}{\ell}}\operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{-\ell o'+\sigma^2}{\sqrt{2}\ell\sigma}\right)\right]$$

where

$$o'=o-\mu^G-\mu^L$$

where $\mu^G$ is probably gaussian mean and $\mu^L$ and $\ell$ are entitled as LD's location and scale parameters respectively.

**EDIT 1**

Probably "D" stands for "distribution", if so then the question is what "L" stands for.

Answer (score 1):

From the references of the paper you are reading, I find that "LD"  means [Laplacian distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution). To quote Wikipedia: *The Laplacian distribution has been used in speech recognition to model priors on DFT coefficients*.